# FK error for some fields inserting

Tags: c#, sql

Here is my `option_table`:

```
OptionID  QuestionID  optionName OptionStatus  count Questioncount  percentage
  30          33          a          1            4      8             50
  31          33          b          1            4      8             50    <-----
  71          48          k          1            3      7             42
  72          48          p          1            4      7             58    <-----
```

Here i am trying to insert somevalues in to `voting_table`.

fine its inserting

```sql
insert into Voting_Table (QuestionID,OptionID)values('33','31')
```

(1 row(s) affected)

trying to insert another one same as above

```sql
insert into Voting_Table (QuestionID,OptionID)values('48','72')
```

but its showing error

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Voting_ta_*Optio*_67B44C51". The
>   conflict occurred in database "webdhabaordering_10-10-12", table
>   "sqldbarv2008.Options_table", column 'OptionID'. The statement has
>   been terminated.

How can I get rid this problem?  Your valuable comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: what's your Primary key table? What's your Foreign key table? Basically this error occurs if you are trying to insert records to Foreign key table where record or ID does not yet exist in your primary table

Comment: Error message clearly says the problem you are facing.. FOREIGN KEY constraint violation. there may be already a value in the column you are referring as Foreign key in Voting Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you had some option table named as **Options_table** that does not have Primary Key may be named as "Option ID" value of 72.

This is why there is a error.

Study about Primary and Foreign Key more.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it says OptionID in sqldbarv2008.Options_table conflict means not existing in other words. may be you haven't committed your last row to options table yet? if that occurs it is visible in the view but underlying database table hasn't got the value until you commit it.